# Worksheets selection based on vba value OR how to convert a string into worksheets array

Tags: excel, vba, split, selection

I'm trying to select differrents worksheets, based on a variable.
All this in a purpose to print those sheets into a pdf.

I've tried with arrays but i don't know much.
So I'm continuing with string and split.
But I have no chance too.

All is ok except the last codeline , the sheets selection.
I receive a Subscript OutOf range
Any advice?

```
Sub Print_Full_Report()

Call Clear_clipboard
Call Stop_Calcul_Screen

LastOverviewRow = WS_Rep_Overview.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
tabtoprint = ""
SelectedDate = Date + 90

For i = 5 To LastOverviewRow
   If WS_Rep_Overview.Range("E" & i) < SelectedDate Then
       Module = WS_Rep_Overview.Range("D" & i).Value
           tabtoprint = tabtoprint & Chr(34) & Module & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & Module & "-Cow" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & Module & "-SubSys" & Chr(34) & ","
   End If
Next i

tabtoprint = Mid(tabtoprint, 1, Len(tabtoprint) - 1)
Sheets(Split(tabtoprint, ",")).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Try: `Sheets(Array(1, 3)).Select`

Comment: Remove all those `& Chr(34)` and it should work.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Perfect thx. I added them hours ago, before I used the split command.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```vb
Sub Print_Full_Report()
    Const template = ",#,#-Cow,#-SubSys"   ' for further use in the loop
    
    ' previous your code ...
    
    ' in the code some redundant variables have been removed
    With WS_Rep_Overview
        SelectedDate = Date + 90
        For i = 5 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
           If .Range("E" & i) < SelectedDate Then
               tabtoprint = tabtoprint & Replace(template, "#", .Range("D" & i).Value)
           End If
        Next i
    End With
    tabtoprint = Mid(tabtoprint, 2) 'remove the leading comma
    ' for debug; check that it prints something like this: Module5,Module5-Cow,Module5-SubSys,Module6,Module6-Cow,Module6-SubSys,Module7,Module7-Cow,Module7-SubSys
    Debug.Print tabtoprint
    Worksheets(Split(tabtoprint, ",")).Select
End Sub
```